# MongoDB: OrderBy for an object specific field within an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

View this object:

```
  "l": "222,41",
  "Rate": "000,01",
  "testable": [
    {
      "title": "lorem ipsum",
      "date:": "2020-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "title": "lorem ipsum",
      "date:": "2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "title": "lorem ipsum",
      "date:": "2020-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to return the dates from the most recent to the least recent in a findOne search. How can I do this via Mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

findOne will only return one element. To get most recent one, you can do `.sort({date: "desc"})`

If you didn't mean that, here is what I did when I wanted to sort comments on an Idea.

```
 Idea.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).populate({ path: "comments", options: { sort: { date: "desc" } } }).then(idea
```

Maybe can get you an idea of how to solve it.

EDIT: Found this also maybe it helps.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-sort-inner-array-in-mongodb

Comment: Thanks in advance for the help, but a populate in this case had no effect because testable is not a collection that is being referenced in this main collection. testable is an array of objects within this collection understand? That is why these objects do not have an ObjectID in them. The question for me is how to make this desc in those date fields that are inside an object that are inside an array.

Comment: Ah, I don't really know then. What you could is get your model and try to sort it by implementing your own sort method for the array of objects. Look at this link for reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/

Comment: I found this also. Check it out. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-sort-inner-array-in-mongodb